# Gnuplot ranges for plot

Tags: linux, macos, plot, gnuplot

Im plotting data which have range of x axes from 0 to 100. I want for x-axes to be devided like in pic:
[image: DESIRED PLOT]

I have this gnuplot code :

```
reset
set terminal postscript enhanced color font "Helvetica" 12 
set output 'lambda.eps'
set xtics (0,1,10,100)

plot 'lambda.dat' u 4:6
```

And obtained this image

[image: My result]

How to get x axis in this scale?

Comment: Do you mean `set logscale x`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried that but still does not work

Comment: Give us your data, maybe there sits the problem?

Comment: I would try to remove `set xtics (0,1,10,100)` and use `set xr [0.1:100]; set logscale x` instead - that xtic at zero in combination with logscale looks suspicious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `set logscale x` will do the job.

```
set nokey
set title "Dynamical dominance criteria example"

set logscale x
set logscale y

set format y "10^{%T}"

plot "lambda.dat" using 1:2 lc 0 pt 12, \
     "lambda.dat" using 3:($2*3):4 with labels
```

For me, the command `set xrange [0.1:100]` was not necessary, the range was chosen automatically. This is the result:

[image: diagram with "set logscale"]

You did not provide your data, so I extracted it with g3data:

```
0.392  1.315e-13  0.392  Mercury
0.725  1.095e-11  0.595  Venus
0.994  9.520e-12  1.144  Earth
1.514  6.491e-14  1.514  Mars
0.994  1.216e-15  0.994  Luna
5.166  8.940e-08  5.166  Jupiter
9.543  4.136e-09  9.543  Saturn
19.24  3.286e-11  15.24  Uranus
30.35  1.843e-11  34.35  Neptune
39.48  1.946e-19  39.48  Pluto
2.797  1.183e-19  2.797  Ceres
40.18  6.960e-23  40.18  KBO
```